# DataTypes and format specifier

Tags: c, types, format

Why the value of the `input` variable is set to zero if I pass incorrectly ordered type specifier for `id` variable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int input;
    char *name=(char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX);
    unsigned short int id;

    printf("\nPlease enter input:\t");
    scanf("%d", &input);
    getchar();//to take \n

    printf("\nEnter name.....\n");
    fgets(name,MAX,stdin);

    printf("\nEnter id: ");
    scanf("%uh",&id);//type specifier should have been %hu
    printf("%d",input);//value set to 0?
}
```

Why is `input` being overridden by `scanf("%uh", &id)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Jyoti Rawat

You have what I call a memory over run error.  Microsoft (Visual Studio) calls it:

> *"Stack around the variable ‘id’ was corrupted"*

Not all computer systems treat memory over runs errors the same.  Visual Studio/Windows catch this error and throw an exception.

[image]

OpenVMS would just execute the instruction and then continue on to the next instruction.  In either case, if the program continues, its behavior will be undefined.

In English, you are writing more bits of data into a variable that cannot contain it.  The extra bits are written to other memory locations not assigned to the variable.  As mention by chux, statements that follow will have undefined behavior.

**Solution:**

As you already know and mention by others, change the format specifier from "uh" to "hu".

**Things to note about your code:**

- As stated my Adrian, using "hu" as a format specifier will work. 
  This specifier expects a pointer to a unsigned short int variable.  [Click here to go to scanf format specifiers wiki page.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications)
- When you specify “%uh”, scanf pares out the %u as the format
  specifier and treats the rest ('h') as text to be ignored.
- The format specifier 'u' expects a pointer to an unsigned int variable (unsigned int *).
- The format specifier 'hu' expects a pointer to an unsigned short variable (unsigned short
  int *).

Comment: `16 bit unsigned short int` - no, it expects a `unsigned short int`, not 16 bit. `unsigned 32 bit variable (unsigned int` - no. `unsigned 16 bit variable (unsigned short int` - no. `int is a signed 32 bit` - no! `unsigned short int is an unsigned 16 bit` - no! `int` doesn't mean 32bit and `short int` doesn't mean 16bit. `short int` has __at least__ 16 bits and `int` has __at least__ 32 bit. There is nothing against both `short int` and `int` having 64 bits. Or 37 bits. Or 19 bits. Or any number of bits greater then their limit.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, not sure if you are questioning the size information I give or the word variable so I will respond to both.  On most 32 bit and 64 bit C implementations, an unsigned short is represented by an unsigned 16 bit int.  I am assuming OP is using either a 32 or 64 bit O/S.  Reference: https://docs.mql4.com/basis/types/integer/integertypes.  When it comes to numerical types SCANF expects a reference to a variable’s stack or heap location and not the actual numerical value.  That why I use the word variable.

Comment: On most, yes, but we are so tiny close to violating it. `long int` on windows has 32 bits, while on linux it has 64 bits. I believe giving students inaccurate information about data types sizes in C is just misleading and will lead to confusion in future. `int` is not 32 bits, it is __at least__ 16 bits (I made an error in my first comment, int is at least 16 bits, not 32 bits, I am sorry). [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models) and [C11 standard 5.2.4.2.1p1](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1p1)

Comment: @ Kamil Cuk and @Gerhardh, I understand your point.  I will remove the bit size information.

Comment: You've nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (After re-reading question/comments):

**Mentat** has nailed the problem! I'll leave some fragments of my original answer, with some additions ...

(1) The warning about using `%uh` should be accepted at face value: to input a `short` integer (signed or unsigned), you need the `h` modifier ***before*** the type specifier (`u` or `d`) - that's just the way `scanf` format specifiers work.

(2) Your code happens to work on `MSVC`, so I missed the point. With `clang-cl` I found your error: As the `h` size modifier is being ignored, the value read in by '%uh' is a (long or 32-bit) `unsigned`, which is being written to memory that you've allocated as a `short` (16-bit) `unsigned`. As it happens, that variable (`id`)is in memory next to `input`, so part of input is being overwritten by the high 16-bits of the 32-bit unsigned you are writing to `id`.

(3) Try entering a value of 65537 for your first input and then the value will still be modified (probably to 65536), but not cleared to zero.

(4) Recommend: Accept and upvote the answer from **Mentat**. Feel free to downvote my answer!

Yours, humbly!

Comment: @Gerhard - You are right! I think my head is in a funny place (as I am, geographically). I have edited my 'answer' accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> Why the value of the input variable is set to zero if I pass incorrectly ordered type specifier to id variable?

```
unsigned short int id;
scanf("%uh",&id);//type specifier should have been %hu
```

`scanf()` first uses `"%u"` and looks for a matching `unsigned *` argument.  As code passed a `unsigned short *` the result is *undefined behavior* (UB).

The result of 0 is not demo'd with `printf("%d",input);`.  Perhaps OP meant `printf("%d",id);`?

In any case, code after the UB of `scanf()` is irrelevant.  It might print `0` today or crash the code tomorrow - it is UB.

Comment: @Gerhardh It would depend on endian too what `id, input` may show.  IAC, its UB.